Did Feynman say: “If you are getting nowhere with an old technology, having a fast technology only gets you nowhere faster!"
A 2016 journal article claims, without references that:

As pointed out by Richard Feynman, “If you are getting nowhere with an old technology, having a fast technology only gets you nowhere faster!”

I once saw a presentation with a similar quote attributed to him.
Did Richard Feynman say this?

Not to be found on the numerous quotation websites, although they do love Richard Feymann...

Not just quotation sites.... this page and the one referenced are only occurrences of this quote that google can find anywhere.  This may not meet the bar for being a valid question on Skeptics.SE since the quote is only seen in one place on the whole www.

I found one other cite, in an interview in Front Line Genomics (with a one-word difference) — but the interviewee is the author of the PubMed Central article, so that's not really independent.

@gidds Thanks for finding this paper! I digged a bit more, and Tak Mak (the author of the paper you found) is the same guy giving the conference I attended and where I heard this quote for the first time!

I found another similar citation — from a different author!  The New Scientist article ‘Smash and grab’ (subscription required) by Marcus Chown on the limits of computation has the line: “After all, as the Caltech physicist and Nobel laureate Richard Feynman said 20 years ago, if you’re going nowhere, then simply doing things more quickly will just get you nowhere faster.”  — However, that's the only other cite I found, so if Feynman did say something like that, I'm guessing the phrasing was rather different.

Thanks! If you want to write an answer with these citations you have found, I'll accept it. I think this provides reasonable evidence that Feynman might have said this (or something close!)

Short answer: there's little evidence that Feynman spoke those exact words; he may have said it privately, or said something vaguely similar in public, or it may be misattributed.
So far we've found only four citations, all with slightly different wording, from two sources.
The oldest (which doesn't mention technology) is:

Smash and grab (subscription required), an article by Marcus Chown published in New Scientist on 2002-06-02:


After all, as the Caltech physicist and Nobel laureate Richard Feynman said 20 years ago, if you’re going nowhere, then simply doing things more quickly will just get you nowhere faster.

The other three all originate from the Canadian medical researcher Tak Wah Mak:

A Journey In Science: ‘Not Lost In Translation’, an article by Tak Wah Mak published on 2016-11-01 in Molecular Medicine (linked in the question):


As pointed out by Richard Feynman, “If you are getting nowhere with an old technology, having a fast technology only gets you nowhere faster!”


Genome Giants — Tak Mak, Senior Scientist, Princess Margaret Cancer Centre, an interview with Tak Wah Mak by Shannon Gunn, published on 2021-11-30 in Front Line Genomics:


Perhaps you remember what the famous physicist Richard Feynman said, ‘If you are going nowhere with an old technology, having a fast technology only gets you nowhere faster’.


A presentation by Tak Mak at a conference attended by the question poster a06e (who probably doesn't remember the exact wording or date).

(I've emphasised the relevant parts of each quote.)

Searching on related terms hasn't shown any similar quotes from Feynman or anyone else.  Feynman is fairly well-known and widely quoted, and his lectures and books are readily available — so if he said something very much like that, you'd expect further references to turn up.  Since they haven't, the likely explanations seem to be:

He said something in public along those lines, but phrased it so differently that we haven't found it (and then Marcus Chown rephrased it, and Tak Mak either borrowed it from there or happened to rephrase it similarly); or

He said it privately, in a source that Marcus Chown had access to (and then Tak Mak either had access to the same source, or used the Marcus Chown article and added the mention of technology); or

He never said anything like that, and Marcus Chown misremembered/​misinterpreted/​misattributed (and Tak Mak took it from him and added the mention of technology).


Without further information, it's hard to narrow down further.
(Note that there are countless references to the general idea of ‘getting nowhere faster’, but no others seem to be related to this question.  I'm also ignoring several links to this very question!)

A through answer, thanks! I agree we cannot reach a definite conclusion here. But at least this answer collects the available references.

Thank you — lacking anything conclusive, I think that's the best we can aim for!  Feel free to comment (or edit) if you can add any relevant details of the conference, or any other likely explanations.
